# Step bar load with animation

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, pug

Here is my progress bar from Vue bootstrap components, you can set default number in data with value: number, I want it to increase it automatically whenever I go to next page. Can anyone assist me with this? I tried with **props** but I have no idea how to do it.

```
   b-progress(:value='value', :max='max', show-progress='', animated='')
```

```
   b-button.next.mt-3.pb-1(v-if="nextLink" :to="{name: nextLink}")
```

```
   RegistrationNav(prev-link="registration_goal" next-link="registration_interview")
```

Comment: you can achieve this using vuex by setting global progress value

Answer (score 0):

For a basic example, without using vue lets imagine this way:

You have a parent component that includes the b-progress and some other component or inout for the user:

```
  <template>
   <div>
       <b-progress :value="currentValue"><b-progress/>

       <button @click="currentValue++">Click to increment </button>
   </div>
  </template>

    export default {
    name: "Login.vue",

    data() {
        return {
            currentValue: 1
               }
         }
    }
```